# Why does a cell's border in bootstrap4 table disappear when i set rowspan to a column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I have this code

```
       <table width="100%" class="table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1">Sr. No</td>
                    <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1">Item No</td>
                    <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1">Item Details</td>
                    <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1" colspan="4">Instructions</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="5">1</td>
                    <td class="text-center px-1 border" rowspan="5">1</td>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">Personal Details</td>
                    <td class="px-1" colspan="4">
                        <ul style="list-style: lower-roman;" class="m-0">
                            <li>This Form is applicable to Resident Indians and there is a separate Form for Non Resident Indians.</li>
                            <li>Currently, Foreign Nationals / Other Country Individuals (OCI) and Persons of Indian Origin (PIO) are not allowed to open PRAN.</li>
                            <li>The applicant shall mention father’s name and mother’s name and shall select the option to be printed on PRAN Card.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">Spouse Name</td>
                    <td class="px-1" colspan="4">If married, spouse name is mandatory.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">Father's Name</td>
                    <td class="px-1" colspan="4">
                        <ul style="list-style: lower-roman;" class="m-0">
                            <li>Father’s name is mandatory.</li>
                            <li>If father’s name has more than 30 digits, you may fill Annexure II for the same.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">Mother's Name</td>
                    <td class="px-1" colspan="4">
                        <ul style="list-style: lower-roman;" class="m-0">
                            <li>Mother's name is mandatory.</li>
                            <li>If mother’s name has more than 30 digits, you may fill Annexure II for the same.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">Date of Birth</td>
                    <td class=" px-1" colspan="4">Please ensure that the date of birth matches as indicated in the document provided in the support.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="17">2</td>
                    <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="17">2, 3 & 4</td>
                    <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="16">Identity, Correspondence & Permanent address details</td>
                    <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">S. No</td>
                    <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">Proof of Identity (Copy of any one)</td>
                    <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">S. No</td>
                    <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">Proof of Address (Copy of any one)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">1</td>
                    <td class="px-1">Passport issued by Government of India.</td>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">1</td>
                    <td class="px-1">Passport issued by Government of India.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">2</td>
                    <td class="px-1">Ration card with photograph.</td>
                    <td class="text-center px-1">2</td>
                    <td class="px-1">Ration card with photograph and residential address</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and the result of the above code is in this picture.
[image: Result of code]

As you can see, wherever I use a colspan, the border disappear. I've tried changing the border-collapse to separate and it kinda works but I get a double line somewhere and just one somewhere else. Any Idea?

Comment: `rowspan="16"` & `rowspan="17"` should be morelike `rowspan="3"`   :)

Comment: No change I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as commented :

> `rowspan="16"` & `rowspan="17"` should be morelike `rowspan="3"` :) – G-Cyrillus
>
> No change I'm afraid – on3ss

To make a coherent code :

```
   <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="17">...</td>
   <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="17">...</td>
   <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="16">...</td>
```

should be (& Ii don't see that many rows below)

```
   <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="3">...</td>
   <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="3">...</td>
   <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="3">...</td>
```

so it matches to the other rows and cells contained and do not overflow somewhere below ....

Example that demonstrates it works :

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  /*push table away from the edges */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table width="100%" class="table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1">Sr. No</td>
      <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1">Item No</td>
      <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1">Item Details</td>
      <td class="font-weight-bold text-center px-1" colspan="4">Instructions</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="5">1</td>
      <td class="text-center px-1 border" rowspan="5">1</td>
      <td class="text-center px-1">Personal Details</td>
      <td class="px-1" colspan="4">
        <ul style="list-style: lower-roman;" class="m-0">
          <li>This Form is applicable to Resident Indians and there is a separate Form for Non Resident Indians.</li>
          <li>Currently, Foreign Nationals / Other Country Individuals (OCI) and Persons of Indian Origin (PIO) are not allowed to open PRAN.</li>
          <li>The applicant shall mention father’s name and mother’s name and shall select the option to be printed on PRAN Card.</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1">Spouse Name</td>
      <td class="px-1" colspan="4">If married, spouse name is mandatory.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1">Father's Name</td>
      <td class="px-1" colspan="4">
        <ul style="list-style: lower-roman;" class="m-0">
          <li>Father’s name is mandatory.</li>
          <li>If father’s name has more than 30 digits, you may fill Annexure II for the same.</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1">Mother's Name</td>
      <td class="px-1" colspan="4">
        <ul style="list-style: lower-roman;" class="m-0">
          <li>Mother's name is mandatory.</li>
          <li>If mother’s name has more than 30 digits, you may fill Annexure II for the same.</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1">Date of Birth</td>
      <td class=" px-1" colspan="4">Please ensure that the date of birth matches as indicated in the document provided in the support.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="3">2</td>
      <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="3">2, 3 & 4</td>
      <td class="text-center px-1" rowspan="3">Identity, Correspondence & Permanent address details</td>
      <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">S. No</td>
      <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">Proof of Identity (Copy of any one)</td>
      <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">S. No</td>
      <td class="text-center font-weight-bold px-1">Proof of Address (Copy of any one)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1">1</td>
      <td class="px-1">Passport issued by Government of India.</td>
      <td class="text-center px-1">1</td>
      <td class="px-1">Passport issued by Government of India.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center px-1">2</td>
      <td class="px-1">Ration card with photograph.</td>
      <td class="text-center px-1">2</td>
      <td class="px-1">Ration card with photograph and residential address</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you.